# Testing email: last email is nil when sent through a background worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, testing, rspec, sidekiq

I'm trying to add some tests for email using [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test), however I'm getting `undefined method 'to' for nil:NilClass`.

The emails are actually processed through a background worker using [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) and I know that they send properly since they work in production and also they would send before I added `require 'sidekiq/testing'` to `spec_helper.rb`

So basically my problem is how do I access the email in Sidekiq? I've tried to let the workers process the email but still got the same error.

spec/support/mailer_macros.rb

```
module MailerMacros
  def last_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
  end

  def reset_email
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries = []
  end
end
```

spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
...
config.include MailerMacros
config.before(:each) { reset_email }
```

config/environments/test.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:8080' }
```

controllers/tickets_controller.rb

```
def create
  @ticket = current_user.tickets.build(params[:ticket])   
  if @ticket.save
    Sidekiq::Client.enqueue(TicketNotifier, @ticket.id)
    flash[:success] = "Your ticket has been submitted successfully."
    redirect_to ticket_path(@ticket)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

part of the spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Tickets" do
  subject { page }

  describe "when creating a new ticket successfully" do
    before do
      login_as_user
      visit new_ticket_path
      fill_in "Subject", with: "Test ticket"
      fill_in "Description", with: "This is a test ticket"
      select 'Billing', from: "ticket[category]" 
      click_button "Submit Ticket"
    end

    specify { last_email.to.should include("admin@email.com") }
    # the rest tests the tickets#show view
    it { should have_selector('title', text: "Ticket #1") }
    it { should have_content("ticket has been submitted successfully") }
    ...
  end
end
```

When I use `specify { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last.to.should include("admin@email.com") }` instead I get the same error.

Comment: can you try this? `specify { MailerMacros.last_email.should include(@user.email) }`

Comment: then I get `undefined method 'last_email' for MailerMacros:Module`, according to the railscasts and similar macros I've run before just `last_email` should work.

Comment: My mistake, you are correct, i guessed without proper thinking. Just gone through that railscast, It is coming `nil:NilClass` in your case, so there is only one reason i can expect is `is the mail actually being sent?`

Comment: yes it is, if I remove `require 'sidekiq/testing'` then Sidekiq actually sends an email to my inbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When requiring `sidekiq/testing` and not `sidekiq/testing/inline`, the jobs are put on the queue but not executed until a command like this is given:

```
Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer.drain
```

I use a helper method like this in my specs:

```
def process_async
  EventWorker.drain
  Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer.drain
end
```

Where EventWorker might be a custom worker in my app, and `Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer` is where delayed mails go by default with Sidekiq.

I can then have a spec like this:

```
#do stuff that should send an email and trigger other sidekiq events
...
process_async
...
#assert the email was sent correctly
```

There is a great explanation of all this on the SideKiq wiki: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing

Comment: Great that worked! Thanks for explaining how it works, I read the wiki but didn't fully understand it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to cmaitchison's answer, I fixed it like this (on their wiki: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing#rspec )

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each) do
    # Clears out the jobs for tests using the fake testing
    Sidekiq::Worker.clear_all

    if example.metadata[:sidekiq] == :fake
      Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
    elsif example.metadata[:sidekiq] == :inline
      Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
    elsif example.metadata[:type] == :acceptance
      Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
    else
      Sidekiq::Testing.fake!
    end
  end
end
```

And do your test like this:

```
describe "Tickets", :sidekiq => :inline do
  subject { page }

  describe "when creating a new ticket successfully" do
    before do
      login_as_user
      visit new_ticket_path
      fill_in "Subject", with: "Test ticket"
      fill_in "Description", with: "This is a test ticket"
      select 'Billing', from: "ticket[category]" 
      click_button "Submit Ticket"
    end

    specify { last_email.to.should include("admin@email.com") }
    # the rest tests the tickets#show view
    it { should have_selector('title', text: "Ticket #1") }
    it { should have_content("ticket has been submitted successfully") }
    ...
  end
end
```